# Is tiled rendering software or hardware rendering technique?

Tags: opengl, rendering, gpu, direct3d

Is [tiled rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_rendering) a software rendering technique such as deferred shading or forward+, or is it happening transparently at the microarchitectural level?

Some resources I read give the intuition that it is might be both. I understand how it works and why it is used for low-powered GPUs, basically rendering into tiles to reduce memory bandwidth. Is there any special preparations required knowing that the device uses tiled rendering if it's transparent to the developers? If it is software technique what is the point of using it on forward rendering hardware?

Comment: Please narrow the question down a bit. There are 3 different questions here, each of which is not exactly short to answer.

Comment: You *linked* to an overview. It's right there on Wikipedia. I'm really not sure what I could add to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, what some people refer to as *tiled rendering* in the context of desktop GPUs is nothing but the *forward+ rendering*, which is the standard forward rendering with light culling prepass. Typically the screen is divided into gird/tiles -hence the name *tiled rendering*- and a shader per-computes the lights affecting these tiles before performing the shading and light calculations. See the 4th slide on this pretension [Advancements in Tiled-Based 
Compute Rendering](http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc2015/presentations/Thomas_Gareth_Advancements_in_Tile-Based.pdf) (these numbers are indices of lights affecting those portions).

*Tiled rendering* in the context of hardware typically used in embedded devices GPUs such as mobiles is a GPU microarchitecture which renderers the scene into tiles over multi passes using fast small expensive memories. See this presentation [Next-Gen Tile-Based GPUs](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/gdc2008_ribble_maurice_TileBasedGpus.pdf), quite old but covers the topic really well. It might not be fully transparent to the developers looking to this video: [Adreno Hardware Tutorial 3: Tile Based Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeySx0TkluE).

Comment: Within the context of Direct3D in particular, 'tiled rendering' refers to this second case. This is usually invisible to the application developer, but you can optimize rendering with a tiled renderer with DirectX 11.1 or later by using ``DiscardView`` on RTV/DSV after ``Present``. This mostly applies to mobile parts.